# Как сократить код, где много разных обработчиков событий, но одна функция-листенер?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Модальное окно можна закрыть (`modalClose()`) 4 разными способами: нажав на крестик (`modalCloseIco`), нажав на кнопку с надписью "Закрыть" (`modalCloseBtn`), нажав на фон модального окна (`modalBackground`) и нажав кнопку Escape.

```
modalCloseIco.addEventListener('click', () => modalClose());
modalCloseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => modalClose());
modalBackground.addEventListener('click', () => modalClose());
window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    if (e.code === 'Escape') {
        modalClose();
    }
});
```

Видно, что существуют несколько обработчиков событий и для каждого срабатывает одна и та же функция. Мне кажется, что было бы удобнее один раз написать функцию и несколько разных обработчиков событий (в идеале в одну строчку через запятую).

Существует ли возможность сократить этот код? В качестве ответа готов принять и обоснование, что нет, нельзя, если такой возможности нету.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для первых трех элементов можно так, так как там реально одинаковое действие. Четвертый к ним не приставить, так как там другое действие. Но по моему так уже лучше :)

```
const elements = [modalCloseIco, modalCloseBtn, modalBackground]

for (const el of elements){
  el.addEventListener('click', modalClose);
}
```

И еще, если вам просто нужно вызывать функцию как колбек без аргументов, то можно вместо конструкции

```
() => modalClose()
```

Писать просто

```
modalClose
```